# Criterion for a splitting field of a quadratic polynomial to be a Galois Extension

Tags: proof-verification, galois-theory

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic, $f(x) = x^2 + bx + c \in F[x]$ an irreducible polynomial. I have to give a criterion for the splitting field $E$ of $f$ over $F$ to be a Galois extension.

Now, we essentially want the polynomial to be separable. Therefore, we want $D(f) \neq 0 \implies b^2 \neq 4c$

And for the case $\text{char }F=2$, we want $b \neq 0$, and if $b=0$, then we want $c$ to be a non-square in $E$

Is this criterion exhaustive?

Comment: In characteristic two, $X^2+c$ is never separable, so if $c$ is a nonsquare, the corresponding extension will never be Galois.

Comment: Why is $x^2 + c$ never separable, even if $c$ is a nonsquare?

Comment: Is it because of the fact that $f'(x) = 0$

Comment: ’Cause over the splitting field, in which $c$ does have a square root, say $\gamma$, you have $X^2+c=X^2-c=(X-\gamma)^2$.